# ComboBoxItem does not show after applying Style to ComboBox

Tags: wpf, xaml

Hello I'm making a WPF program. But I have a problem with ComboBox

I need a combo box style like this code.

```
<ComboBox Height="28" Background="White" VerticalContentAlignment="Center" Width="120">
    <ComboBox.BorderBrush>
        <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="0,20" MappingMode="Absolute">
            <GradientStop Color="#FFABADB3" Offset="0.05"/>
            <GradientStop Color="#FFE2E3EA" Offset="0.07"/>
        </LinearGradientBrush>
    </ComboBox.BorderBrush>
    <ComboBoxItem Content="Content1" IsSelected="True"/>
    <ComboBoxItem Content="Content2"/>
</ComboBox>
```

This code works well.

After dividing Style and View, this code does not work.

Actually the style applied to ComboBox but ComboBoxItems do not show.

What is the problem?

Style part

```
<Style x:Key="ComboBoxLikeTextBox" TargetType="{x:Type ComboBox}">
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="ComboBox">
                <ComboBox Height="28" Background="White" VerticalContentAlignment="Center">
                    <ComboBox.BorderBrush>
                        <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="0,20" MappingMode="Absolute">
                            <GradientStop Color="#FFABADB3" Offset="0.05"/>
                            <GradientStop Color="#FFE2E3EA" Offset="0.07"/>
                        </LinearGradientBrush>
                    </ComboBox.BorderBrush>
                </ComboBox>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

View part

```
<ComboBox Style="{DynamicResource ComboBoxLikeTextBox}">
    <ComboBoxItem Content="Content1" IsSelected="True"/>
    <ComboBoxItem Content="Content2"/>
</ComboBox>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So you create a whole style, with only one setter. And you use that setter to replace your combobox template with a template that contains a different combobox, that has all the properties you want, but makes no effort to populate itself with the retemplated combobox's children. Of course there are no children in that combobox; you never gave it any. And there's no need to create a new template just to set the height and whatnot. Templates are heavy artillery and you don't need that for a simple style like this.

Use style setters to set the properties you want to set, not to nuke the whole control. Like so:

```
<Style TargetType="ComboBox" x:Key="ComboBoxLikeTextBox">
    <Setter Property="Height" Value="28" />
    <Setter Property="VerticalContentAlignment" Value="Center" />
    <Setter Property="Width" Value="120" />
    <Setter Property="BorderBrush">
        <Setter.Value>
            <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="0,20" MappingMode="Absolute">
                <GradientStop Color="#FFABADB3" Offset="0.05"/>
                <GradientStop Color="#FFE2E3EA" Offset="0.07"/>
            </LinearGradientBrush>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

Comment: Thank you very much! It is very useful!